# Python, Selenium Webdriver. Сменить ориентацию экрана (портрет / ландшафт)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Нужно заставить Selenium Webdriver сменить ориентацию экрана с портретной на ландшафтную, средствами Python3.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Заранее спасибо )